# PDCurses getmouse receives no arguments?

Tags: visual-studio, pdcurses

I'm using PDCurses in Windows with Visual Studio 2017. The library was compiled with MSVC compiler, with which I made the win32a version as per the [README](https://github.com/Bill-Gray/PDCurses/blob/master/win32a/README.md). I did some tests and was able to link the library to some small test programs.

Then I tried to test the example found in [this howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/mouse.html) for how to use mouse but Visual Studio tells me that the `getmouse` function doesn't receive any arguments (it should receive a `MEVENT*` argument). Intellisense points me to the declaration

```
unsigned long getmouse(void);
```

Looking at `curses.h` I found the bit

```
#ifdef NCURSES_MOUSE_VERSION
# define getmouse(x) nc_getmouse(x)
#endif
```

`nc_getmouse` does indeed receive the correct argument:

```
int     nc_getmouse(MEVENT *);
```

Perhaps I forgot to set some options when building the library?

Could someone give me an orientation here? It is my first time using this library.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're using the ncurses mouse API, instead of the native PDCurses API. Which is fine, but if you want to do that, you should #define NCURSES_MOUSE_VERSION before including curses.h. From the PDCurses documentation:

```
nc_getmouse() returns the current mouse status in an MEVENT
struct. This is equivalent to ncurses' getmouse(), renamed to
avoid conflict with PDCurses' getmouse(). But if you define
NCURSES_MOUSE_VERSION (preferably as 2) before including
curses.h, it defines getmouse() to nc_getmouse(), along with a
few other redefintions needed for compatibility with ncurses
code. nc_getmouse() calls request_mouse_pos(), which (not
getmouse()) is the classic equivalent.
```